# JupyterLab warning: "Could not determine npm prefix: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"

Tags: node.js, jupyter-lab

I have the following error while starting JupyterLab (on Windows 10 x64):

```
[W 2023-07-02 06:52:30.881 ServerApp] Could not determine npm prefix: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

What does it mean and how to fix it?

I already have the latest version of standalone installation of **Node.js** (20.3.1), also I've installed **Python package** (`pip install nodejs`).
Version checks work as expected. Node.js folder is in `Path` variable (system-wide). But the warning still remains.

Comment: This warning can be ignored, unless you want to use LSP which is not yet released for Lab 4.0.

Comment: What does `npm prefix -g` return for you?

Comment: @krassowski, got it, thank you. `npm prefix -g` returns `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\npm`.